# How can I fix "Cannot build and run Embedded C Code"

Tags: c, gcc

I am learning embedded C. I am trying but giving error. I think this error due to mingw64. I am sharing full code

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "test/test.h"

int main()
{
  Test_t *deneme = test_init(5);
  int a = test_getCount(deneme);
  printf("one %d", a);
  test_updateCount(deneme, 10);
  int b = test_getCount(deneme);
  printf("two %d", b);
  return 0;
}
```

test.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
  int count;
} Test_t;

Test_t *test_init(int number);
void test_updateCount(Test_t *tester, int number);
int test_getCount(Test_t *tester);
```

test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "test.h"

Test_t *test_init(int number)
{
  Test_t *deneme = malloc(sizeof(Test_t));
  deneme->count = number;
}

void test_updateCount(Test_t *tester, int number)
{
  tester->count = number;
}

int test_getCount(Test_t *tester)
{
  return tester->count;
}
```

I am developing with VSCODE. test.c and test.h files is in directory ./test.
build command is `gcc .\main.c -o main.exe` and build error

```
C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccSxcYgu.o:main.c:(.text+0x13): undefined reference to `test_init'
C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccSxcYgu.o:main.c:(.text+0x23): undefined reference to `test_getCount'
C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccSxcYgu.o:main.c:(.text+0x4b): undefined reference to `test_updateCount'
C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccSxcYgu.o:main.c:(.text+0x57): undefined reference to `test_getCount'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: It's simple, all your unresolved errors reference functions in test.c. You need to add test.c to your build command `gcc main.c test/test.c -o main.exe`. You do this in VSCode by editing tasks.json.

Comment: @john thank you. it is work. how can I add every c file to this command ? I have job if I write every c files :D

Comment: VSCode doesn't work very well with multiple file builds. You can use wild cards, e.g. `*.c` for all C files in a directory. But if you have a lot of files it's probably better to use a build system like CMake,

Comment: I solved with cmake. thanks guys

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: C and C++ are very distinct programming languages. Don't tag the C code with C++. Linux and embedded tags are also irrelevant to you question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed cmake. and I created CMakeLists.txt project directory.

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(test)

# Kaynak dosyalarını belirtin
set(SOURCES
    main.c
    "test/test.c"
)

# Derleme hedefi oluşturma
add_executable(test ${SOURCES})
```

after I created build file on project directory and go to build file inside with command prompt. I run `cmake ..` command. and after go to project directory. I want to every save file and build and run. so I installed nodemon.
last command run `nodemon --watch "./" --ext "c" --exec "cmake --build ./build && .\build\Debug\test.exe"`

Answer (score 0):

The compiler needs to know the implementation of `test_init()`
, `test_updateCount()` and `test_getCount()` to link your program.

But first, rhe file `test.h` needs an include guard.  You can achieve this by placing`#pragma once` as the first line of your header file.

The following command should build it:
`gcc -o main.exe main.c test/test.c`

Additionally, I recommend using a Makefile or a modern programming IDE (as recommended by [Lundin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/584518/lundin)) to streamline your build process.

Comment: Or just use a modern programming IDE and don't worry about make files and linker input.

Comment: Maybe I am old-fashioned, but in my opinion, programmers should be able to compile and build a program without a modern programming IDE.

Comment: Yes that's old fashioned and we used to waste so much time on various command line junk back in the 1990s, time that could have been spent doing actual programming. Get a tool chain which comes with as little friction and setup as possible, so that you can focus on the actual job.